# Have Griffon generate jnlp with resource tag with os attribute but no arch attribute

Tags: jnlp, java-web-start, griffon

Griffon uses it's lib directory structure to generate resources tags.  For example if my project has a structure of:

```
lib 
 | 
 |--linux
       | foo.jar
```

After running 'griffon package webstart' the jnlp file will have the following resource tag

```
<resources os='Linux' arch='x86_64'>
    <jar href = "linux/foo.jar" />
</resources>
```

The box I'm running the webstart off of for some reason is not loading the jar file unless I remove the arch attribute.

1. Is there a way I can tell griffon to not add an arch attribute?
2. How does girffon decide that my jar is for a specific arch?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to configure a flag to tell Griffon to avoid adding a value for the "arch" attribute. However, you can "hack" your local copy of the $GRIFFON_HOME/scripts/_GriffonPackage.groovy and modify line 600

https://github.com/griffon/griffon/blob/master/subprojects/griffon-scripts/src/main/groovy/_GriffonPackage.groovy#L600

Perhaps you'd like to open a JIRA ticket for the configuration flag?

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/griffon